# Cannot find control in EditTemplate via OnRowEditing event

Tags: asp.net, gridview, edit

I have a `GridView` like so:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdPractices" PageSize="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" 
    CssClass="linkGrid" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="grdPractices_OnSorting" OnRowDataBound="grdPractices_OnRowDataBound"
    OnRowEditing="grdPractices_OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="grdPractices_OnRowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="grdPractices_OnRowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" meta:resourcekey="PracticeName" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Name" ItemStyle-Width="400px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" meta:resourcekey="Code" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Code" ItemStyle-Width="200px" />
        <asp:TemplateField meta:resourcekey="SiteName" ItemStyle-Width="200px" SortExpression="SiteName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SiteName") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="lstSites" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField meta:resourcekey="NumOfUsers" ItemStyle-Width="200px" SortExpression="NumOfUsers">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnCommand="OnLinkButtonCommand" CommandName="ViewUsers" Text='<%# Eval("NumOfUsers") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="False" ShowCancelButton="True" 
            ShowInsertButton="False" ShowEditButton="True" EditText="Edit"
            CancelText="Cancel" UpdateText="Update" meta:resourcekey="Edit" ItemStyle-Width="200px" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and here is the code for the OnRowEditing event:

```
protected void grdPractices_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    this.grdPractices.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    var sitesDropDown = this.grdPractices.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Controls[0].FindControl("lstSites") as DropDownList;

    if (sitesDropDown == null)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I cannot get a hold of the `lstSites` control, which lives in the EditTemplate. I've tried using the following:

- this.grdPractices.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Controls[0].FindControl("lstSites")
  as DropDownList;
- this.grdPractices.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lstSites") as
  DropDownList;
- this.grdPractices.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControlRecursive("lstSites")
  as DropDownList;

The result is always the same, a `NULL` is returned.

How on earth are you supposed to get a control in a row when in the OnRowEditing event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, what I was not doing, after this line:

`this.grdPractices.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;`

was then rebinding the grid's data. So after rebinding the data, and then calling:

```
var sitesDropDown = this.grdPractices.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControlRecursive("lstSites") as DropDownList;
```

I am now able to interact with the `siteDropDown` variable since it now contains a reference to the `lstSites` control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `GridViewRow` as following...

```
protected void grd_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) 
{
     GridViewRow selectRow = grd.Rows(e.NewEditIndex);
     DropDownList sitesDropDown =(DropDownList)selectRow.Cells[2].FindControl("lstSites"); 
}
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but no joy I'm afraid. I will tinker with it a bit, but it's times like this I HATE ASP.NET WebForms and much prefer ASP.NET MVC. Much less hassle.